# get maximum value a can take without using a list (python)

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, max

Creating a ten time iteration where **a** can take a random value from 0 to 9, i would like to know when **a** take its maximum value without storing all the values of **a** into a list.

```
from random import randint

for i in range(0,9):
    a = randint(0,9)
    print (a)
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to just print the highest value of the full loop i.e just 1 value, or the highest value every time the loop iterates and the next random number beats the current record?

Comment: `max(randint(0, 9) for i in range(9))` no list, it's a generator expression

Comment: @AK47 Yes, only 1 value, the highest above all others

Comment: @Chris_Rands oh its true, i wasnt using a list. The code i give is just the beginning of how i would want to do it. Using a list, is the thing i wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this is what you're looking for?

```
from random import randint

a = float('-inf')

for i in range(0,9):
    b = randint(0,9)
    a = b if b > a else a

print (a)
```